# How to change border of iframe so that it blends in with the background, instead of default?

Tags: iframe, border, default, blend

I have an iframe, but I dont like the default, "dented" into the page look. How can I change this so that it appears at the same level as the surrounding page and blends right in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can use the frameborder attribute.

```
<iframe src="..." frameborder="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS:

```
IFRAME { border:0px; }
```

Comment: Without CSS, the entire site is without CSS and it's outside my control to change since it's my company's web site.